# Running a Task Infinitely either in foreground and background

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, nstimer, background-process

I will be very thankful If someone make a classified answer for this. Even-though I have read more documents regarding this background execution, experienced a strange behaviors when I implemented those in coding.

I have my application supporting the background modes (GPS) , and I can see that location updates are printed regularly in log. I have a NSTimer running which will send the location updates to my server every 1 hr. It is strange that the timer is working for many hours and suddenly it got stopped.

I have two questions in my mind which I keep on asking me ,even-though I have read some apple documents.

1 - Is it possible to run a task infinitely either in background / foreground using timers ? if the timers aren't the option , what API I can use to run task infinitely .

2 - If the user have an option to disable Location Services for my app, I am gone  . I  don't want the user to disable the Location service for my particular app. Can that be done ?

Plese HELP !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really answer your first question however keep in mind: You should do “minimal work while running in the background.[...] Apps that spend too much time executing in the background can be throttled back by the system or killed“ ([Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)).

Did you request the `UIBackgroundMode:location`? If not, you can only execute code in the background for a finite amount of time.

Regarding your second question: Before being able to get the users location an app asks the user about a permission. This permission can be denied, you'll then have no access to the users location. Even if the permission is granted, the user can withdraw the permission at any time. So, yes, the user is able to disable location service for your app.

Comment: Thank you for response and your reply makes me clear in some areas.Wish that you will help me a bit. Actually I want to run a tasks infinitely even if the application is in background and foreground at any cost.Thats the reason I went for the GPS. Battery not a problem as of now. Do you have any idea how to achieve that ?

Comment: So you're only using GSP to be able to run in the background, without using the GSP data? If yes, I'm pretty sure your app will be rejected by Apple.

Comment: I am using the GPS Data as well. It is like every n minutes I am posting the GPS Co-ordinates to the server.

Comment: Now that will be not a problem na. Do you know how to run a tasks every n minutes. I am really getting mad to make it work.